# marker.js inside custom modal rather than provided popup

Tags: javascript

I am using marker.js (https://markerjs.com) in a custom modal and would like to annotate within the modal but based on the positioning, I can't do that.  marker.js does provide a popup which I will use for now but would prefer to annotate within my existing modal rather than opening yet another modal to annotate.

[image]

```css
element {
    visibility: visible;
    font-size: 16px;
    user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 118px;
    left: 26px;
    width: 620px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.  I can't find any settings in marker.js to override the default positioning but maybe someone with more experience knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

marker.js has a targetRoot property that can be set to the image parent rather than using the body.  This allowed me to use in a modal.